# Can I cross the US border by bus the first time with a newly-issued visa?

Tags: visas, usa, buses, russian-citizens

I just got a US visa and I would like to take a bus tour from Toronto to New York (Russian Passport). Someone just told me that I should cross the border only by plane the first time, and only after that I will be able to cross the US border by bus. Is it true?

Comment: What kind of visa? is there anything on the visa that says you need to come in by plane first time?

Comment: What class of visa? How many entries?

Comment: Visitor visa, student visa, work visa or what? What is your country of birth? and nationality?

Comment: The advice you received seems to be confused by the procedures for the visa waiver program, which are indeed different when entering by land and by air, and the land procedures can even be different depending on whether you recently entered by air.  But there's no *requirement* to enter first by air, and anyway the visa waiver program does not apply to you because you are traveling with a visa.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your visa is specifically annotated that you can only enter by air (and I've never seen such an annotation on a US visa) then you can enter via any means you want - including by road/bus.